# Visual Studio unable to get developer license

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone

[image: Error 0x80072F8F]

This error is obtained when trying to obtain developer license from Visual Studio 2015. How to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

This error number typically appears when using Windows Update with a wrong system time. You might want to verify your system clock.